# Highcharts - Axis minPadding and maxPadding not working

Tags: highcharts, padding

I was adding some padding to my chart because I want to control the space between the actual chart and the container, and I encountered a problem.
Look at mi first fiddle, all seems legal but the padding isn't being applied:
https://jsfiddle.net/9r2Lqmpj/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        minPadding: 0.4,
        maxPadding: 0.4
    },
    yAxis: {
        startOnTick: false,
        minPadding: 0.2
    },
    series: [{
        data: [129.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

But if I duplicate the "xAxis" key, this time without the categories array, which seems highly wrong, for no reason it works:
https://jsfiddle.net/v0rj1xkg/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        minPadding: 0.4,
        maxPadding: 0.4
    },
    xAxis: {
        minPadding: 0.4,
        maxPadding: 0.4
    },
    yAxis: {
        startOnTick: false,
        minPadding: 0.2
    },

    series: [{
        data: [129.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

I wasn't expecting at all that this worked, in fact, I discovered it by mistake. Why is it working only when I repeat the xAxis key definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties `minPadding` and `maxPadding` don't work with category axis type. Use `min` and `max` options instead.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {...},
    ...
}, function() {
    var xAxis = this.xAxis[0];
    this.update({
        xAxis: [{
            min: xAxis.min + 0.2,
            max: xAxis.max - 0.2
        }]
    }, true, true, false);
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/96s30khd/

Answer (score 1):

Well Agustin, not much of a discovery rather than a common logic there in your second scenario. I am not really sure what you're trying to achieve, but having `xAxis` defined twice is not necessary. Just remove the first one to get the same result, so it looks like your second one is overwriting the first one. Have a look at your fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/xcmq869s/ which looks the same to me. Also it might be the case that the padding doesn't work with categorical data, so it works fine when no categories are specified. U can certainly alter the padding with removed categories.

On the other note, if you want to keep your x-axis labels and add only outer spacing, try using the `chart.spacing` config option as in the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/xcmq869s/1/.